# How to link tensorflow with mingw

Tags: tensorflow, linker, mingw

I wanted to create ai for my game so I install [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) I download [libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-2.6.0.zip](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-2.6.0.zip)) but when I compile the following error apeared:
[a sample of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSJiI.png)

I try to compile with c
(`gcc main.cpp -o main.o -ltensorflow -L src/lib -I src/include`
`gcc main.o -o main.exe -ltensorflow -L src/lib -I src/include`)
instead of c++
(`g++ main.cpp -o main.o -ltensorflow -L src/lib -I src/include`
`g++ main.o -o main.exe -ltensorflow -L src/lib -I src/include`)
but the problem persist.
I think the problem is that I use the wrong library (it finished by .lib instead of .a and no "lib" before tensorflow) but I'm sure I download the right library.

(I'm not english fluent so if things are not clear you can correct me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fix: using relative path instead of real path for include
because I want to put the library inside my working directory and not in the mingw path